# My Apple Watch never receives local notification send by the hosting iOS app

Tags: uilocalnotification, apple-watch

I intend to use the code below to send a notification from hosing iOS app to Apple Watch app

```
    var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate()
    localNotification.alertBody = ""
    localNotification.alertAction = ""
    localNotification.category = "GameStart"
    localNotification.userInfo = payload.toDictionary() as [NSObject : AnyObject]
```

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

according to https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html, the Watch App should receive the notification under certain circumstances, I tried
- lock the screen
- put iOS app into background

But the Watch App never receive any notifications from iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to successfully receive [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/) on Watch running WatchOS2. Make sure option 'Mirror iPhone Alerts from' is turned on for your app (it's a setting inside Watch(MyWatch) app on iPhone), your iPhone app is not running, iPhone is asleep and locked and the watch is on your wrist.